# sqoop export from hive to sql server error

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, sqoop

we are trying to export data from hive to sql server table

```
sqoop export -D mapred.child.java.opts='\-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom' --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://' --username $$$$ --password #### --table ib_c3 --columns BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_NAME,CONTRACT_NUMBER,SERVICE_LINE_ID,SERVICE_LINE_NAME,SERVICE_LINE_STATUS,STS_CODE,INSTANCE_ID,SERIAL_NUMBER,ITEM_NAME,QUANTITY,INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,WARRANTY_TYPE,WARRANTY_END_DATE,SHIP_DATE,PARTY_SITE_ID,LAST_DOS,IB_PRODUCT_TYPE,PRODUCT_FAMILY,ERP_ITEM_TYPE,SKU_LIST_PRICE -m 1 --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --export-dir /app/dev/SmartAnalytics/Apps/CSP/hivewarehouse/csp.db/csp_ib_c3_export --input-null-string '\\N' --input-null-non-string '\\N' -- --schema staging
```

During the export we are getting the below error from sqoop. Can someone help us with this issue.

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:220)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:46)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:644)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:84)
>           ... 10 more
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatementBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1299)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtBatchExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1209)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1173)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlOutputFormat$AsyncSqlExecThread.run(AsyncSqlOutputFormat.java:231)